# Looking for help fixing a question put on hold due to requiring a "specific, factual quote of a claim"

Tags: discussion

I posted the question "https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/are-the-chiropractic-excellence-videos-on-youtube-real" last night, which was put on hold.  The comment suggests "Please limit this to a specific, factual quote of a claim."  I am having some difficulty interpreting this request, and also having difficultly complying; and am seeking advice.

The meta-reason I posted this question was:

- I believe that most (all?) Chriopractors are quacks, and from other Chriopractor-related posts on this site the evidence bears this out.
- The huge majority of videos I've run across on youtube involving Chriopractors basically hitting all the bullet points of the benefits or exposition on a vague problem the patient is having, then show a video of an adjustment, and sometimes a patient testimonial follows.  These are very easy to dismiss, because they rely on a lot of the same techniques that other pseudoscience medical claims do -- plus the studies often referenced in the first bullet point.
- The "Chriopractic Excellence" videos, though, call into question a lot of what I believe about Chriopractors -- because as I mentioned they are treating very specific medical problems, and it should be very easy to verify if these treatments were successful.
- If the evidence presented in the videos was really representative, I feel like the discussion about Chriopractic treatments in general would be very different.
- However researching more about the "Gonstead School", which the videos are very closely linked to -- at their core they do believe in the sublexations are the root cause of these issues -- and this belief is at the very heart of why people label Chiropractic techniques as placebo at best.

To even further narrow this down -- the video I was asking questions about really crystalized a lot of issues regarding Chiropractic techniques onto a specific focal point.  Either they are legitimate and the video are what they claim to be -- or they are not legitimate and the video is a complete fabrication or there is some important element that is being hidden from the viewers.

I am having trouble crystallizing this tension into a single quote though.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You are asking an answerer to tackle a huge subject, that is too broad.

[Entire books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=zHxockt9CWQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_v2_summary_r&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) have been written on the subject. Wikipedia has an [article page covering the controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiropractic_controversy_and_criticism) which is over 5,000 words long.

That's not a reasonable request for an answerer to tackle the whole Chiropractic industry.

Also, we are looking for definitive answers, and there is no way to write a definitive answer on all the things wrong and right in these videos.

Instead, we ask you to nail it down to one specific, clear claim, so we can provide the evidence for and against that claim.